# Getting different answers between Numpy and manual calculation

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, linear-algebra, numpy-ndarray

I have several matrices:

```
A=np.array([[-4, -1, -3] ,[1, -4,5],[ 3,4,3],[-5, -1,2]])
b = np.array([[-1], [4],[-4],[-2]])
x=np.array([[ 0.58732799],[-1.19370936],[-0.22879177]])
```

I want to calculate the residual, r = Ax-b

```
r=A@x-b

print(r)

[[ 0.53077272]
 [ 0.21820656]
 [ 0.30077121]
 [-0.20051414]]
```

If I take the norm of r, I get:

```
print(np.linalg.norm(r))
0.678235
```

If I do the same thing in `numpy`, I get a different answer:

```
x,residuals,rank,sigma=np.linalg.lstsq(A,b,rcond=None);
print("Vector x:\n " + repr(x))
print(residuals)


Vector x:
 array([[ 0.58732799],
       [-1.19370936],
       [-0.22879177]])
[0.46000302]
```

Namely, the `residuals` are not identical. Does someone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html says:

> **residuals:**
>   Sums of residuals; squared Euclidean 2-norm

It is the square of what you calculated in the first example.

```
>>> 0.678235 * 0.678235
0.460002715225
```